# Unity AssetBundle Load Path Folder

Tags: unity3d, path, assets

возник вопрос с путем к ресурсам (.png), собрал АссетБандл , и теперь не могу получить из него файл так как он находится в папках которые я запаковал внутри Бандла[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как извлечь файл внутри Бандла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файлы из бандла получаются вполне банально - по имени. С помощью метода [LoadAsset(string name)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.LoadAsset.html), который нужно вызвать у бандла, в котором лежит ваш файл.

Так же, хочу заметить, что если в вашем бандле (в разных бандлах - норм) будет два файла с одинаковым именем (даже лежащих в разных папках) по запросу будет выдаваться всегда только один из них.

Comment: То есть по любому нужно указывать уникальное имя файлу?

Comment: @TarasKlymenko, для всех файлов внутри одного бандла. Если бандлов несколько - имена между ними уникальными быть не обязаны.